# Names of huge number of input images using gdal_merge_raster.py

Tags: gdal-merge

I am trying to make a stack including huge number of images using gdal_merge_raster.py.

Is there  a way to avoid writing all the input images names?

Answer (score 1):

I also suggest to build a virtual raster. Using the batch command processing on Windows, it is as simply as

```
gdalbuildvrt -allow_projection_difference index.vrt *.tif
```

If the images use paletted colours, it is necessary to expand that to rgba first:

```
for %%N in (D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL50\*.tif) DO gdal_translate -of vrt -expand rgba %%N D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL50\%%~nN.vrt
gdalbuildvrt -allow_projection_difference index.vrt D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL50\*.vrt
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend that you use gdalbuildvrt instead of gdal_merge_raster if you work with a huge amount of images. This will create a small intermediate file for "lazy computing" (you make all calculations at the end, and only what is necessary.

Then you can use Python to create a list of your files and create your vrt accordingly. The vrt file can then be used as a merged file. See posts on gdalbuildvrt for more details. For example this one : [gdalbuildvrt error, when using in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81788/gdalbuildvrt-error-when-using-in-python/81793?noredirect=1#comment112804_81793)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to get a single merged raster, instead of VRT, you can use gdalbuildvrt along with gdal_translate:

```
gdalbuildvrt temp.vrt *.tif
gdal_translate -of GTiff temp.vrt final_merged.tif
```